# Assign colors to specific bins of a colormap with Matplotlib/Python to create gradients at uneven intervals

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have read various S.O. posts as well as Matplotlib documentation/examples to implement a colormap with colors at arbitrary places, which I call "anchor points" or bins, and have the gradients calculated between these anchor points.

The feature that I thought would come close to what I intend to do is BoundaryNorm. The function takes a bounds list, which I understood as anchors at specific values based on the data ranges, and not at specific bin positions along the colormap.

Please see below what I intend to achieve.

[image: Colormap with uneven intervals]

It is an interactive colormap with handles, that indicate color changes, and can be dragged while the gradient is recalculated between them. I am not after the interactive part, but rather after the uneven gradients between the handles. Notice that the intervals are different.

Now see what I have tried, which is a plot painted with the colors defined by an arbitrary list, a LinearSegmentedColormap which creates a cmap with the gradients, and a ListedColormap cmap. Then I define the norm list based on the data range (10 to 80), which I understood as color change points:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as pplot

# Data declaration
NUM_COLORS  = 256
VAL_MIN     = 10
VAL_MAX     = 80
color_list  = [(0.4, 0.5, 1), (1, 0, 0.43), (0.7, 0.25, 0.9), (0.3, 0.4, 0)]    # RGB normalized to [0, 1]
bounds      = [10, 15, 20, 80]  # Anchor values located between the data range

# Plot space definition
N       = 50
X, Y    = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, 1), np.linspace(VAL_MIN, VAL_MAX, N))
Z       = np.ones((len(X), len(Y)))

# matplotlib initialization based on the data
fig, ax     = pplot.subplots(1, 1, figsize = (3, 10))
list_cmap   = mplot.colors.ListedColormap(color_list)
segm_cmap   = mplot.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("Segm_cmap", color_list, N = NUM_COLORS)
norm        = mplot.colors.BoundaryNorm(boundaries = bounds, ncolors = NUM_COLORS)
pcm         = ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, Z, norm = norm, cmap = segm_cmap)
ax.imshow([[0, 0], [1, 1]], cmap = segm_cmap, interpolation = 'bicubic', extent = [0, 10, VAL_MIN, VAL_MAX])
fig.colorbar(pcm, ax = ax, extend = "both", orientation = "vertical")
pplot.show()
```

When you run it, you will already see my problem, that is, the colorbar has the colors changing at the norm values but no gradient, and the mesh has the gradient but without the colors changing at the norm (if I add the argument "norm = norm" to the imshow() line, it just paints with the first color).

If we consider 256 bins to assign colors to, I would rather assign colors to them instead of data values, since I intend to achieve this uneven gradients, that is, some intervals will use more bins than others.

Maybe you can provide me some guidance on how to achieve this, if at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LinearSegmentedColormap` has the possibility to spread the colors unevenly. Instead of just color values, it also accepts tuples `(val, color)` where `val` is a value between 0 and 1, and `color` the corresponding color.

To map your bounds to the interval `[0, 1]`, `np.interp()` can be used.
The tuples then look like:

```py
[(0.0, (0.4, 0.5, 1)),
 (0.07142857142857142, (1, 0, 0.43)),
 (0.14285714285714285, (0.7, 0.25, 0.9)),
 (1.0, (0.3, 0.4, 0))]
```

The following example code gives image data with more intermediate values, `origin='lower'` and `interpolation='bilinear'` to `ax.imshow()`. Cubic interpolation makes an interpolation that smooths out the values at the start and the end. The default norm is used. A `BoundaryNorm` creates a step function, without smoothing.

(The abbreviations for `matplotlib` and `pyplot` are changed to the standard ones, as non-standard abbreviations confuse me a lot, making it much harder to compare code to the docs and tutorials.)

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Data declaration
NUM_COLORS = 256
VAL_MIN = 10
VAL_MAX = 80
color_list = [(0.4, 0.5, 1), (1, 0, 0.43), (0.7, 0.25, 0.9), (0.3, 0.4, 0)]  # RGB normalized to [0, 1]
bounds = [10, 15, 20, 80]  # Anchor values located between the data range
color_tuples = [(i, color)
                for i, color in zip(np.interp(bounds, [bounds[0], bounds[-1]], [0, 1]), color_list)]

# matplotlib initialization based on the data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(3, 10))
segm_cmap = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("Segm_cmap", color_tuples, N=NUM_COLORS)
norm = plt.Normalize(vmin=bounds[0], vmax=bounds[-1])
img = ax.imshow(np.linspace(VAL_MIN, VAL_MAX, 256).reshape(-1, 1),
                cmap=segm_cmap, norm=norm, interpolation='bilinear',
                origin='lower', extent=[0, 10, VAL_MIN, VAL_MAX])
fig.colorbar(img, ax=ax, extend="both", orientation="vertical")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: segmented colormap from boundaries]

Comment: I deleted my previous comment because you clearly said that "Instead of just color values, it also accepts tuples (val, color)". Appreciate your guidance, which allows me to continue working.